# Is there any way to distinguish in onResume between starting activity because of Intent and others cases

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume

Is there any way to distinguish while in onResume()  between  two cases:
1) activity is brought to the front because it was started by Intent from other activity
2) activity's onResume called without new Intent (for example screen was off and on, or maybe other situations when activity was not started by user explicitly)

In first case I want to do some long operations, for example load data from web.
In second case I dont want to do nothing (because user didn't ask explicitly, but screen just went off for second)
I mean situations, when activity is not recreated and it's onCreate is not called. (if recreated, I need to do long operation anyway)
As far as I tried in both cases getIntent() returns original intent. In both cases onNewIntent is not called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the state diagram here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

There are several differences between both situations. Particularly, onPause, onStop and onRestart are only called when the app is resumed. I think your best bet is to turn on a boolean flag in all of these methods, which is turned off at onCreate.

Comment: Thanks. It helped in case with screen turning on/off (onStart is not called in that case).